# Purpose of shortening length modifiers in *printf* functions

Tags: c

What are the shortening length modifiers (i.e., `h`, `hh`) in the **printf**
function family for?

What's wrong printing shorter integers as ints (`"%d"`) or unsigneds (`"%u"`) given that that's how they'll be passed in anyway?

Comment: Opinion based. But there might be subtle differences on certain platforms (e.g. with other than 2's complement integers). And symmetry with `scanf` (where they are obviously needed) might also be an aspect.

Comment: One more: they allow a platform to use optimised code. For an 8-bit CPU e.g. it is easier to div/mod an 8-bit `char` instead of a full-sized (typically 16 bit) `int`. Similar for more exotic architectures possibly.

Comment: When I've considered the question before, symmetry with `scanf()` -- to the point of sharing format strings for input and output -- was the best I could come up with.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: On >=16 bit plaforms you might be correct. But on small 8 bit CPUs optimised conversion functions will safe a lot of run-time (at the cost of space).

Comment: Try printing the value of `signed char c = -1;` using `"x"`.

Comment: @pskocik: sry, meant x not d.

Comment: @alk Thanks. That's a very good point, although it's easily handled by passing `(unsigned char)c`.

Comment: @PSkocik: I doubt the cast helped. Did you try this?

Comment: @alk It works well. I believe casting chars to uchars and shorts to ushorts before printing them as %x or %u will always do the job of the h or hh length modifiers.